# remove element in dom4j

Tags: java, xml, dom4j, removechild

```
<root>
 <elm id="1"/>
 <elm id="2"/>
 <elm id="3"/>
 <elm id="4"/>
</root>
```

I want to leave id="2" in the dom, 
how can domj4 to remove the other three ?

result:

```
<root>
 <elm id="2"/>
</root>
```

Answer (score 6):

What have you done so far? Well, I would go from the scratch.

- Try to get the `Document` using `DocumentHelper.parseText(xmlStr)`
- Then get the root element of the document using `Document.getRootElement()`
- After getting the root element, you can loop through all child elements using Element.getElements() or its variants, and check the attributes of each element using `Element.getAttributes()` or its variants.
- After determining all three elements, which are not required. You can use `detach()` method to remove those from the document. For example `elm1.detach()`, `elm2.detach()`, and `elm4.detach()`. Better still make a list of those element, you want to remove, and then `detach()` in a loop.

Cheers.

NOTE: Document.remove(Element elem) method will not work if the element is not the immediate child. For more see the [docs](http://www.dom4j.org/dom4j-1.6.1/apidocs/).